# ERROR: spinnaker_python-2.6.0.156-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python, terminal, pip, pyspin, spinnaker-cam

I am trying to install the wheel "spinnaker_python-2.6.0.156-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl"", but this error keeps popping up in the terminal. I am running this line from my local drive.
`pip install spinnaker_python-2.6.0.156-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl"`
I am running this on Python 3.9.10.
Why is this error showing up, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Python 3.9 … cp37 … See?

Comment: I do not understand. (edit: I understand now. Thank you)